# Data that's been sent from client is not valid for my django-rest api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is what React client is using to send user sign-up data(to be stored in the database):

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user', {
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
        },
        'body': JSON.stringify(data),
    })
```

Here is the `data` that is being sent:

```
username: ["palash"]
contact: ["singhpalash0@example.com"]
dob: ["2021-04-08"]
password: ["password"]
```

data after `JSON.stringify()`

```
{'wantTo': 'signup', 'username': ['palash'], 'contact': ['singhpalash0@example.com'], 'dob': ['2021-04-03'], 'password': ['password'], 'confirmPassword': ['password']}
```

Here is the response I'm getting back from the server(along with a status code of `400`)

```
contact: ["Not a valid string."]
dob: ["date has wrong format. Use one of these format instead: YYYY-MM-DD"]
password: ["Not a valid string."]
username: ["Not a valid string."]
```

`view.py`

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(serializer.initial_data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        wantTo = serializer.data.get('wantTo')
        username = serializer.data.get('Username')
        password = serializer.data.get('Password')
        if wantTo == "signup":
            email = serializer.data.get('Email')
            dob = serializer.data.get('dob')
            
            user = User(username=username, contact=email, dob=dob, password=password)
            user.save()
            return Response({'detail': 'registered!'})
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "contact", "dob", "password")
```

`model.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    contact = models.CharField(unique=True, blank=False, max_length=64)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: You are sending arrays instead of just the string value. It should be `'username': 'palash'` instead of `'username': ['palash']`

Comment: alright, now I'm sending just the string and not the array, it's interesting to notice that instead of the above response, now I'm getting an empty object, it's still a 400 Bad Request though

Comment: I am getting an empty object returned by printing serializer.errors, I have printed json too, it is same as before

Comment: if the if in `if wantTo == "signup":` is false, it goes to the 400 response and probably without serializer errors. Check your variables and make sure you are getting what you need.

Comment: OMG Yes! that was it, wantTo field was not in my serialzer, so `serializer.is_valid()` function was not keeping it in the `serializer.data` resulting in the value of variable `wantTo` being none. On my part I don't think not considering this fact was my major mistake, it was the fact that I didn't realise that 400 will be sent if one of my `if` statements fail, and not just on the failuire of `is_valid()`